# How to flexibily design a custom ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a question regarding the design of a custom `ContentProvider` implementation. Most examples on the web assume an SQLite database in the background but that is not necessarily true in our case. In fact, we don't know yet what will be the source of the data as this data is provided by a 3rd-party supplier.

At the moment, our internal dummy `ContentProvider` implementation (for testing purposes) implements the `ContentProvider#query(...)` method which returns a `Cursor` object. However, this might be undesirable for the 3rd-party supplier as they will most likely have non-relational/non-SQL-like data. We strive to setup the interface/system in such a way to make it as flexible as possible so that, no matter how they data is stored on the other end (the 3rd-party supplier's end), our code only needs to be adjusted minimally once it is clear how that data is made available over their `ContentProvider`.

What I would like your opinion about now is:

- Is `ContentProvider#query(...)` the correct way to go about this, i.e. is `Cursor` an appropriate return type also fro non-relational/non-database-related data? If so, that would mean that the `Cursor` interface would have to be implemented accordingly by our 3rd-party supplier?
- I believe another way to go about this is to use  a `MatrixCursor`. It would still return a `Cursor` reference but the rows in that 'matrix' can be of type `Object`. This would leave quite  a bit of flexibility.

I'd love to hear your ideas and opinions about this. I might have overseen something completely.

Comment: Cursor is just a Cursor, you can use a MatrixCursor but can also extend AbstractWindowedCursor to be more flexible (especially in huge data sets), you can also use a CursorWrapper to slightly change original Cursor behaviour

Comment: pskink, Does this mean that, whatever cursor I choose, returning a Cursor is definitely the way to go in our case?

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused as to whether a Cursor is the correct structure here when accessing non-database-like data.

Comment: yes you can use Cursor for any data not only for database stuff

Comment: Ok, get it & if we do so, simply implement the needed methods of the CursorWrapper interface. Thank you for your help.

Comment: CursorWrapper is not an interface, its soncrete class

Comment: Sure, you're right. I meant to override them.